# password_reset doesnt work

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions, password

Im trying to use $_POST method after password reset submit action
here is the code

```
add_action( 'after_password_reset', 'action_function', 10, 2 );
function action_function( $user, $new_pass ){
    if (isset( $_POST['password_1'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password_1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
    }
}
```

however it doest get fired

any tip?

also the **reason** I need the password is using for another app credentials
for example the following code shows how I use $_POST during profile_update

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {
    // password changed...
    if ( ! is_admin() && isset( $_POST['password_1'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password_1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
        global $wpdb;
        global $current_user;
        $script_db = new wpdb('db', 'pass', 'user', 'localhost');
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $email = (string) $current_user->user_email;
        $password = (string)  get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'user_pass2', true );;
        $query   = $script_db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$script_db->prefix}np_users WHERE email = %s", $email );
        $results = $script_db->get_results($query);
        if(count( $results ) > 0) {
            $id = $results[0]->id;
            $script_db->update('np_users', array(
            'password' => $password
            ),array('id'=>$id));
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```

Comment: I dont want to store the raw format, I have another app installed on subdomain which use different format of hashing the password , I should store the credentials to use it for registration the user in db (writing after purchasing some packages) so I dont want to do anything stupid regarding to passwords

Comment: I updated the question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use these hooks for that. If you wan't to use the same password for some other app, then it's crucial, that the password will always be the same.

So the best way will be to make sure it will be always true. How? By taking care of that.

WordPress uses `wp_set_password` function every time the password is changed. There are no hooks inside of it (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L0), but [it's pluggable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) - so you can write your own version of it. So do it:

```
function wp_set_password( $password, $user_id ) {
    // Keep original WP code
    global $wpdb;

    $hash = wp_hash_password( $password );
    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->users,
        array(
            'user_pass'           => $hash,
            'user_activation_key' => '',
        ),
        array( 'ID' => $user_id )
    );

    wp_cache_delete( $user_id, 'users' );

    // and now add your own
    $script_db = new wpdb('db', 'pass', 'user', 'localhost');

    $custom_hash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
    $userdata = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $script_db->update(
        'np_users',
        array( 'password' => $custom_hash ),
        array( 'email' => $userdata->user_email )
    );
}
```

This way the password will always be synchronized. (For example your code would break the passwords if admin changed the password for user).

You also don't have to store second hash as user meta. And it performs less queries - you don't have to select user by email and then update the password using his ID - you can just run the update.

All you need to do is to put that function in your plugin.

Comment: wow, I didnt know that, can I put this code in my custom plugin ? and how can I call it ? Im trying to make it work after every WP update ?

Comment: Its absolutely helpful !! thank you

Comment: You don't have to call it. This function is pluggable, so WordPress will use it. All you have to do is to put such function in your plugin.

Comment: sure thanks for opening new doors to my eyes ! Im still learning WP

Comment: one more problem is I dont create the create the user on my second app as they register in wp,, I create the registration on woocommerce purchase from some categories, so I think I should check for availability of $email anyway?

Comment: Im not sure whats the problem , but I should save password because I dont create user on wordpress registration, I just create for some users who buy woocommerce package , so this line of code after $custom_hash should work

update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', $custom_hash);

Comment: it doesnt get fired , Im not sure if I put it in the right direction

Comment: I believe this function doest run at all, I tried to even change the first part and put same password for every user but it reads from user Input

Comment: I tested it extensively, I doesnt work on WooCommerce registration, I even removed the function from the wp-includes, it still create user from front-end
Im sorry Im gonna un accept the answer

Comment: I almost understand my problem : my whole registration system is WooCommerce, so this code only works with wp-login registration, so I should edit core or using this hook instead woocommerce_customer_reset_password

Comment: That’s why you have to ask a complete questions - you haven’t even mentioned WooCommerce I your question - and if you did, all you question would be off topic.

Comment: thanks I found the answer and I accepted it again, I do it right now with 3 hooks, do you know any equivalent to this function in WooCommerce ? and is it pluggable?